# When clicking inside the block, an external click is triggered

Tags: reactjs

Can I, when clicking on an internal click, do so that the top click does not work?
[image]
I have a pop up which is inside the block at the click on which it opens. Therefore, I need to implement this logic to close it.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

  onClick() {
    console.log(111)
    // I need when click onClick1 this not trigger
    // open popup
  }

  onClick1() {
    console.log(222)

    // close popup
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>

          tatatata
          <div onClick={this.onClick1.bind(this)}>vavavavava</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `stopPropagation` method on the event given to the `onClick1` event handler to stop it from bubbling up to the other elements.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    console.log(111);
  }

  onClick1(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(222);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
          tatatata
          <div onClick={this.onClick1.bind(this)}>vavavavava</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```